# debugging React.js app in VS Code gives: ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React.js and during debugging React app in VS Code I get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at eval (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:4:23)
at Function.n.run (browser.min.js:3)
at l (browser.min.js:3)
at browser.min.js:3
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (browser.min.js:3)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, can you share the entire code of that page, maybe it's just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this how you should do it,

```
const MY_VARIABLE   = 'foobar';
export {MY_VARIABLE};
```

Or you could do it like this,

```
const MY_VARIABLE   = 'foobar';
export default MY_VARIABLE;
```

The difference between the first and second approach is, the in the first approach when you import it you have to import it like this

```
import { MY_VARIABLE } from '../../your-path-here';
```

While in the second approach you can do it like this;

```
import FooBar from '../../your-path-here';
```

Again it depends on how you want to use it depending on your requirement or use case.